# JavaCV/FFmpeg causes crash only on Lollipop

Tags: android, opencv, ffmpeg, javacv

I get reports of this crash from users of my app on Galaxy Note devices running Android Lollipop (might happen on other devices but the majority of my users have Galaxy Note because it's a drawing app). Below is the relevant code from my ASyncTask which exports a series of images (plus audio) to a video file using JavaCV/FFmpeg, and the stack trace from the reported crash. It works fine on my Note 8.0 running KitKat (there's no Lollipop update available for that device), and works fine in Lollipop on the emulator, so I'm having a hard time tracking down the cause and don't know what to do.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(final File... params) {
    FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(params[0],canvas_width,canvas_height, 0);
    FrameGrabber audiograbber = null;
    if(audio!=null) audiograbber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(audio);
    Frame audioframe;
    Frame image;
    AndroidFrameConverter converter = new AndroidFrameConverter();

    try {
        recorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
        recorder.setFrameRate(framerate);
        recorder.setPixelFormat(0);
        if(audio!=null) {
            audiograbber.setFrameRate(framerate);
            audiograbber.start();
            recorder.setAudioChannels(audiograbber.getAudioChannels());
            recorder.setSampleRate(audiograbber.getSampleRate());
        }
        recorder.start();

        Bitmap drawframe = createBitmap(canvas_width, canvas_height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(drawframe);
        Paint p = new Paint();

        for(int frame=0; frame<movielength; frame++) {
            if(isCancelled()) break;
            publishProgress(frame);

            //code to draw image

            image = converter.convert(drawframe);
            recorder.record(image);
        }

        if(isCancelled()) {
            bgbitmap.recycle();
            drawframe.recycle();
            return "Cancelled";
        }

        if(audio!=null) {
            while((audioframe = audiograbber.grabFrame()) != null) {
                recorder.record(audioframe);
            }
        }

        recorder.stop();
        bgbitmap.recycle();
        drawframe.recycle();
        if(audio!=null) audiograbber.stop();
        return "Saved "+params[0];
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "Failed";
}
```

-

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/treltexx/trelte:5.1.1/LMY47X/N910CXXU1COH4:user/release-keys'
Revision: '21'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 12039, tid: 12053, name: GCDaemon  >>> com.weirdhat.roughanimator <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'sart/runtime/gc/collector/mark_sweep.cc:381] Can't mark invalid object'
    r0 00000000  r1 00002f15  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
    r4 b366bdb8  r5 00000006  r6 00000002  r7 0000010c
    r8 00000001  r9 b446f550  sl b4429000  fp 9a975c60
    ip 00002f15  sp b366b008  lr b6db9cb9  pc b6ddd3ac  cpsr 60070010

backtrace:
    #00 pc 0003b3ac  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
    #01 pc 00017cb5  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
    #02 pc 000188c7  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
    #03 pc 00015165  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
    #04 pc 00012fac  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
    #05 pc 00242f17  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort()+170)
    #06 pc 000ad991  /system/lib/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+1360)
    #07 pc 0013ec53  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::gc::accounting::HeapBitmap::AtomicTestAndSet<art::gc::collector::MarkSweepMarkObjectSlowPath>(art::mirror::Object const*, art::gc::collector::MarkSweepMarkObjectSlowPath const&)+422)
    #08 pc 0013ed27  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::collector::MarkSweep::MarkObjectParallel(art::mirror::Object const*)+142)
    #09 pc 0013ff23  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::collector::MarkSweep::MarkRootParallelCallback(art::mirror::Object**, void*, art::RootInfo const&)+26)
    #10 pc 0025893d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ReferenceMapVisitor<art::RootCallbackVisitor>::VisitQuickFrame()+1024)
    #11 pc 00258cad  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ReferenceMapVisitor<art::RootCallbackVisitor>::VisitFrame()+224)
    #12 pc 0024c8e9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::StackVisitor::WalkStack(bool)+276)
    #13 pc 0024e617  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::VisitRoots(void (*)(art::mirror::Object**, void*, art::RootInfo const&), void*)+994)
    #14 pc 0013ef9f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::collector::CheckpointMarkThreadRoots::Run(art::Thread*)+126)
    #15 pc 0025b44d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadList::RunCheckpoint(art::Closure*)+296)
    #16 pc 0013dc0d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::collector::MarkSweep::MarkRootsCheckpoint(art::Thread*, bool)+96)
    #17 pc 0014165d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::collector::MarkSweep::PreCleanCards()+172)
    #18 pc 001417d3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::collector::MarkSweep::MarkingPhase()+126)
    #19 pc 001418b9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::collector::MarkSweep::RunPhases()+176)
    #20 pc 00138527  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::collector::GarbageCollector::Run(art::gc::GcCause, bool)+246)
    #21 pc 0015865b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::CollectGarbageInternal(art::gc::collector::GcType, art::gc::GcCause, bool)+1426)
    #22 pc 00159af5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::ConcurrentGC(art::Thread*)+56)
    #23 pc 000003ef  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat
```

Comment: meet the same crash

Comment: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/gc-debug might help you debug it. Though, you may also be hitting a known bug in the OS:  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37020958